# Store text with line breaks in hidden input

Tags: jquery, html, input, line-breaks

I want to store the text output of any non-hidden parts of a div in a hidden input text field. However, the div contains `<br/>` tags, and those aren't being stored.

The code I am using to store the div in the input is:

```
function updateHidden()
{
    var clone = $('#coverSample').clone()
                        .appendTo('body')
                        .find(':hidden')
                        .remove()
                        .end()
                        .remove();

    //var content = clone[0].outerHTML || 
    var myText = clone.html();
    $("#coverToSubmit").val(myText);

    //$('<div>').append(clone).html();
}
```

How can I ensure that the line breaks are also stored in the input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jquery [data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method to store this data associated to a dom element.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you simply do:

```
var myText = clone.html();
$("body").data("coverToSubmit", myText);
```

then, use

```
$("body").data("coverToSubmit");
```

to extract the data

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you're using `clone()`. Why not just do `var clone = $('#coverSample').html()`? That should save the HTML tags inside as well.

**Update:** Here's a fiddle with it working: http://jsfiddle.net/Mt444/.